# Shell: short version of `<application> & disown; exit` for replacing the terminal with a gui application

Tags: shell, application, disown

On a tiling window manager starting a gui application from the terminal emulator leaves the terminal open alongside the newly started window.

A solution for this is

```bsh
$ <application> & disown; exit
```

which is quite a bit to type. Is there another solution apart from writing a function to do the job?

I was expecting `exec` to do the trick but that leads to the terminal window being closed right after the gui

Comment: `exec setsid <application>`

Comment: That works and I can set an alias for it. Why no answer?